# How to use ng-show and ng-hide in ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Here i have the code:

```
<ul dnd-list="list" ng-controller="Modalcontrol">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)">
    {{item.card_name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<span ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex=$index">Add </span>
<md-card class="card" ng-show="$parent.selectedIndex == $index" >
  <form name="colorForm" class="addcontdrag" >
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Add text</label>
    </md-input-container>

    <span>
      <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Save</md-button>
      <i class="material-icons" ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex=$index">clear</i>
    </span>
  </form>
</md-card>
```

In this code i want to hide the md-card when i click the close button. Show the md-card by using $parent.selectedIndex=$index. But i dont know how to hide the md-card using this one.

If anyone know please help me.

Thanks Advanced...

Comment: There is no controller on your `md-card` + Your `ng-repeat` is for the `li` tag only

Comment: Please provide all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to place your `md-card` inside li tag to get the `$index`.

```
<ul dnd-list="list" ng-controller="Modalcontrol">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)">
    {{item.card_name}}
    <span ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex=$index">Add </span>
   <md-card class="card" ng-show="$parent.selectedIndex == $index" >
    <form name="colorForm" class="addcontdrag" >
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Add text</label>
    </md-input-container>

    <span>
      <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Save</md-button>
      <i class="material-icons" ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex=$index">clear</i>
    </span>
  </form>
  </md-card> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is ok sir. But i want to hide the div. how??